# For a singleton Class, can we still create separate instance?

Tags: java, oop, singleton

For example, if the singleton is:

```
class Singleton 
{ 
    private static Singleton single_instance = null; 
  
    public String s; 
  
    public Singleton(String test) 
    { 
        s = "Hello I am a string part of Singleton class"; 
    } 
  
    public static Singleton getInstance() 
    { 
        if (single_instance == null) 
            single_instance = new Singleton("valueA"); 
  
        return single_instance; 
    } 
}
```

Is it ok to do following?

1. If the class is called from one place, such as Class A, we use this singleton, `Singleton.getInstance();`
2. If the class is called in all other place, create a new instance: `Singleton singleton = new Singleton();`

Comment: That's not a singleton.

Comment: Sounds like you want a static field in class `A` of type `Singleton`

Comment: Also, for the some code, if we remove this line: if (single_instance == null)., then this is not singleton anymore, and the code is useless because we can just call new Singleton("valueA") any where. Right?

Answer (score 2):

"Singleton" is a specific pattern where a key idea is that you don't let other classes create instances of your class.

If you make the constructor publicly accessible, you no longer follow the "singleton" pattern and you should call this something else to avoid confusing other people on your team.

You could call it a "shared instance" maybe.

> Is it ok to do following?

As long as it doesn't cause problems later on, it's fine. It's hard to say more without knowing the specifics of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the situation is as simple as "All class A's should use one Singleton instance, and all other classes should use another Singleton instance", then no, probably not. A better solution may be a factory:

```java
public class PseudoSingleton {
    ...
}

public class PseudoSingletonFactory {
    
    private static PseudoSingleton generic = new PseudoSingleton();

    public static PseudoSingleton create( Class caller ) {
        if ( caller == A.class ) {
            return new PseudoSingleton();
        else {
            return generic;
        }
    }
}
```

However, this is pretty ugly and I highly recommend redesigning this. It has the potential to create a lot of technical debt down the road.

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes, you can do this. `Singleton` is just the name of an `Design Pattern` [(documentation here)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) that shows you how to implement something in a specific way to get some benefits through this.

If your requirements does not fit by the `Singleton Pattern`, than of course you can implement something else. But than it is not called any more `Singleton`.

If I get your requirements correct, maybe you can call it `Twoton` :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:
This is not ok. Because it violates the singleton pattern, by allowing more than `one instance`.
The `constructor` must be `private`.

As already mentioned before, you should refactor your code to avoid usage of singleton because it has some downsights (e.g. lack of testing).
It's nowadays more of an `anti pattern`